# Synonym to "very convenient"

Tags: synonyms

Can you list me candidates that can replace "quite convenient","very convenient", and sort according to the degree? I don't want to use the word "very" in my text.

For example, "using this editing technique instead of the technique in regular software is very convenient since it greatly saves you time"

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want synonym for 'very' or 'convenient'? For 'very' you can use 'pretty convenient'.

Comment: I want a word stronger than "convenient", so I don't have to use very.

Comment: Well `convenient` can mean a lot of different things which are slightly varied in their sense. So please give the context of use. The sentence itself would be better!

Comment: For example, "using this editing technique instead of the regular technique is very convenient since it greatly saves you time".

Comment: In the example you give, I would simplify it to > "using this editing technique instead of the regular technique is _better_ since it greatly saves you time"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would first need to define your context of the word *convenient*, so that when we increase the intensity of its meaning, we would know what you actually expect.

Let me presume the following expectations about the intensive context of the word.

- efficient: higher amount or more intense results, while needing lesser amount of effort.
- i.e., [enter link description here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/intense)intense consequences, without needing intensive effort.
- [expedient](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/expedient): can be executed quickly, conveniently, without much impediment to itself.
- [expeditious](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/expeditious): a more modern version of the word *expedient*.
- [efficacious](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/efficacious): successful in producing a desired or intended result; effective

Notes about the word *expedient*:

- The words *expedient*, *expeditious*, *expedite* are derivatives from the Latin "*expedi-*"  ~to speed things up, be ready, on the go, unencumbered (*ped* => foot, etymologically common with Sanskrit *pad*).
- The most well-known early use of *expedient* is in 1 Corinthians 6:12 & 10:23 of  the Bible -
  *all things are permissible but not all things are expedient*.
- US usage of the word has skewered itself towards a more negative/selfish direction. US dictionaries list the *expeditious/beneficial/speedy* meaning of the word as "archaic".

The original meaning of *expedient* in the two verses in the Bible carries the connotation of

- quick and efficient results
- beneficial to the cause of the community without indulging in unnecessary expenses and efforts.

Lucky for us Americans, the words *expedited* and *expeditious* come to our rescue. However, outside the US, I believe you could still use the word *expedient* safely and closely to its biblical meaning.

Therefore you could say

> *This editing technique is expeditious, expedient and efficacious*.

That is to say in a few words to mean "*This editing technique is speedy, with low impediment to execute, saves time and brings self-benefits to the  user, and has effective and efficient results that we desire.*"

However, to management circles, the two trigger words are *effective* and *efficient*, because these two words have been *parlanced* (bounced around in idiomatic speech). For example the phrase, *the effective and efficient organisation*. Therefore, to sell a technique to management, you would say

> *This technique is expeditious, effective and efficient.*

One has to be reminded, that management circles have an ongoing infatuation with the phrase "*efficiency is not effectiveness*", where it means one can be efficient where the efficiency does not bring any benefits.

To a teenager or young adult, the trigger words are *intense* and the slightly out of fashion *awesome* and *wicked*. Such young folks love an *intense* measure of ambiguity.

> *This technique is awesome, wicked with intense results.*

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is comprehensive. I will choose the word "expedient".

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for *appropriate* or you can use *quite appropriate*.